# How to plot multiple lists on the same plot as bar and line plots?

Tags: python

I have 4 lists - yr_list, income_list, expense_list and profit_list.

I would like to show yr_list on x-axis, income_list as bar chart on y-axis, expense_list as bar chart on y-axis and profit_list as line chart on secondary y-axis. How do I do that?

[image]

```
[2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
[3174507.7278688527, 4666571.258098361, 4757771.147540984, 3347104.209836066, 3475079.6604590164, 3282371.708852459]
[2957117.5807213113, 4133987.196196721, 4617619.47947541, 3218228.637639344, 3402567.9462295077, 3226548.6240000003]
[217390.14714754096, 532584.0619016397, 140151.66806557373, 128875.57219672124, 72511.7142295087, 55823.084852459004]
```

Comment: There are many ways to do that. What exactly was the problem when you tried it?

Comment: fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax2 = ax1

ax1.plot(yr_list, income_list, 'g-')
ax2.plot(yr_list, expense_list, 'b-')
ax2.plot(yr_list, profit_list, 'y-')

Comment: What about this code in your comment? Is there a problem with it?

Comment: Yes, I can only plot line chart, I need to plot bar for income_list and expense_list. Line plot for profit_list on the same plot. The profit_list should refer to secondary y-axis due to the scale.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using matplotlib. Did you try to use this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

Comment: I did, my issue is with plotting multiple subplots. Need guidance on the code.

Comment: You need to be more specific about what your *actual* problem is. We cannot read your mind what you already know and have tried.

Comment: *What* is your issue with multiple subplots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yr_list = [2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]
income_list= [3174507.7278688527, 4666571.258098361, 4757771.147540984, 3347104.209836066, 3475079.6604590164, 3282371.708852459]
expense_list = [2957117.5807213113, 4133987.196196721, 4617619.47947541, 3218228.637639344, 3402567.9462295077, 3226548.6240000003]
profit_list = [217390.14714754096, 532584.0619016397, 140151.66806557373, 128875.57219672124, 72511.7142295087, 55823.084852459004]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig = plt.figure()
# To get the axis of the figure
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
# Add bar plot
ax.bar(yr_list, income_list, color = 'b', width = 0.25, label='Income')
# Add the second bar plot with a small shift
ax.bar([yr + 0.25 for yr in yr_list], expense_list, color = 'g', width = 0.25, label='Expense')
# Adds line plot
ax.plot(yr_list , profit_list , color = 'y', label='Profit')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-81-06b7f38b3961> in <module>()
      2 fig = plt.figure()
      3 ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
----> 4 ax.bar(yr_list + 0.00, income_list, color = 'b', width = 0.25)
      5 ax.bar(yr_list + 0.25, expense_list, color = 'g', width = 0.25)
      6 ax.plot(yr_list , profit_list)

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: I have added the comments. In my earlier experiment, I used np.array and hence didn't get the error. But now I have made this for the list input